# What does it mean to enable CB when a rollback is false?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, circuit-breaker

what is the difference?

1.

```
--deployment-configuration "deploymentCircuitBreaker={enable=true,rollback=false}"
```

2. 

```
--deployment-configuration "deploymentCircuitBreaker={enable=false,rollback=false}"
```

What does it mean to enable CB when a rollback is false?

Answer (score 1):

Circuit breaker is a new feature to help ECS detect that your service deployment failed and stop your service from continuously trying to restart tasks.  I haven't used this feature directly but, based on documentation, if you enable circuit breaker without rollback, you will get the benefit of ECS failing fast and not thrashing your tasks until something tells it to stop trying (e.g. CloudFormation or manual intervention).

References:

- http://docs.amazonaws.cn/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_DeploymentCircuitBreaker.html
- [https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/announcing-amazon-ecs-deployment-circuit-breaker/#:~:text=With%20this%20feature%2C%20Amazon%20ECS,the%20need%20for%20manual%20intervention](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/announcing-amazon-ecs-deployment-circuit-breaker/#:%7E:text=With%20this%20feature%2C%20Amazon%20ECS,the%20need%20for%20manual%20intervention).

Comment: I didn't ask for the circuit breaker itself. Look at the enable state. I asked the difference between the two.

Comment: im not sure what in the answer is not satisfactory, if you don't enable circuit breaker, your task may thrash and ECS may keep restarting it until something external stops it.  If you enable circuit breaker, you ECS will be better at detecting a failure and stop trying to restart it and mark it failed faster.  Setting enable=false is equivalent to not specifying the deploymentCircuitBreaker option: circuit breaker won't be used.

Comment: I think what the OP means is what is the difference between rollback=false and rollback=true?  Would rollback=false leave the service in a broken state?